# How can I display PIL image to html with render_template flask?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I tried to display my edited image with PIL package, when I tried to make it to display on the html `<img src=''></img>` it doesn't appear anything, but I see the file name on inspect elements was `<img src="<_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001EDA8F76E00>">`. How do I make the edited image display properly?

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/api/games/shipper/image/", methods=["GET"])
def games_shipper():
    ... # My stuff up here
    image_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(image_io, "PNG")
    image_io.seek(0)
    return render_template('image.html', image_data=image_io)
```

**image.html**

```
   ... // My stuff up here
   <body>
      <center>
         <image src="{{ image_data }}"></image>
      </center>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the data from the buffer with the [`getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) function and then convert it. The base64 encoded data can then be passed to the src parameter as a data url.

```
from base64 import b64encode

@app.route("/api/games/shipper/image/", methods=["GET"])
def games_shipper():
    ... # My stuff up here
    image_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(image_io, 'PNG')
    dataurl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + b64encode(image_io.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    return render_template('image.html', image_data=dataurl)
```

If you pass the image as a dataurl, there is no way to shrink the string. However, there is the possibility of serving the file as pure image data. You can use [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file) in another endpoint for this. You serve the page (template) in one endpoint and the image file in a second.

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/image')
def game_shipper():
    # ...
    image_io = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(image_io, format='PNG')
    image_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        image_io,
        as_attachment=False,
        mimetype='image/png'
    )
```

```
  <body>
    <center>
      <img src="{{ url_for('game_shipper') }}" />
    </center>
  </body>
```

Comment: Is there by any chance to not make it with very long url  `(b64encode)` of the image?

Comment: @Interesting I revised my answer. The image is served similarly to when you distribute a static file. I am available for any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode your image in Base64 to display it in the `img` tag directly, see e.g. [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

The traditional way to display images in Flask templates is to save the image in Flask's `static` folder and link to it in your template like so

```html
<body>
      <center>
         <image src="/static/{{image_name}}.png"></image>
      </center>
   </body>
```