# How to generate a PNG image in PIL and display it in Jinja2 template using FastAPI?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint that is generating PIL images.  I want to then send the resulting image as a stream to a Jinja2 `TemplateResponse`.  This is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```py
import io
from PIL import Image

@api.get("/test_image", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def test_image(request: Request):
    '''test displaying an image from a stream.
    '''
    test_img = Image.new('RGBA', (300,300), (0, 255, 0, 0))

    # I've tried with and without this:
    test_img = test_img.convert("RGB")

    test_img = test_img.tobytes()
    base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(test_img).decode("utf-8")

    return templates.TemplateResponse("display_image.html", {"request": request,  "myImage": base64_encoded_image})
```

With this simple html:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Display Uploaded Image</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>My Image<h1>
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
   </body>
</html>
```

I've been working from these answers and have tried multiple permutations of these:

[How to display uploaded image in HTML page using FastAPI & Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263202/how-to-display-uploaded-image-in-html-page-using-fastapi-jinja2)

[How to convert PIL Image.image object to base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826335/how-to-convert-pil-image-image-object-to-base64-string)

[How can I display PIL image to html with render_template flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848602/how-can-i-display-pil-image-to-html-with-render-template-flask)

This seems like it ought to be very simple but all I get is the html icon for an image that didn't render.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

I used Mark Setchell's answer, which clearly shows what I was doing wrong, but still am not getting an image in html.  My FastAPI is:

```py
@api.get("/test_image", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def test_image(request: Request):
# Create image
    im = Image.new('RGB',(1000,1000),'red')

    im.save('red.png')

    print(im.tobytes())

    # Create buffer
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Tell PIL to save as PNG into buffer
    im.save(buffer, 'PNG')

    # get the PNG-encoded image from buffer
    PNG = buffer.getvalue()

    print()
    print(PNG)

    base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(PNG)

    return templates.TemplateResponse("display_image.html", {"request": request,  "myImage": base64_encoded_image})
```

and my html:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Display Uploaded Image</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>My Image 3<h1>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run, if I generate a 1x1 image I get the exact printouts in Mark's answer.  If I run this version, with 1000x1000 image, it saves a red.png that I can open and see.  But in the end, the html page has the heading and the icon for no image rendered.  I'm clearly doing something wrong now in how I send to html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. I'll make a new section for each to keep it clearly divided up.

---

If you want to send a base64-encoded PNG, you need to change your HTML to:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
```

---

If you create an image of a single red pixel like this:

```
im = Image.new('RGB',(1,1),'red')
print(im.tobytes())
```

you'll get:

```
b'\xff\x00\x00'
```

That is not a PNG-encoded image, how could it be - you haven't told PIL that you want a PNG, or a JPEG, or a TIFF, so it cannot know. It is just giving you the 3 raw RGB pixels as bytes `#ff0000`.

If you save that image to disk as a PNG and dump it you will get:

```
im.save('red.png')
```

Then dump it:

```
xxd red.png

00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 0001 0000 0001 0802 0000 0090 7753  ..............wS
00000020: de00 0000 0c49 4441 5478 9c63 f8cf c000  .....IDATx.c....
00000030: 0003 0101 00c9 fe92 ef00 0000 0049 454e  .............IEN
00000040: 44ae 4260 82                             D.B`.
```

You can now see the PNG signature at the start. So we need to create that same thing, but just in memory without bothering the disk:

```
import io
import base64
from PIL import image

# Create image
im = Image.new('RGB',(1,1),'red')

# Create buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Tell PIL to save as PNG into buffer
im.save(buffer, 'PNG')
```

Now we can get the PNG-encoded image from the buffer:

```
PNG = buffer.getvalue()
```

And if we print it, it will look suspiciously identical to the PNG on disk:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x90wS\xde\x00\x00\x00\x0cIDATx\x9cc\xf8\xcf\xc0\x00\x00\x03\x01\x01\x00\xc9\xfe\x92\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Now you can base64-encode it and send it:

```
base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(PNG)
```

---

**Note**: I only made 1x1 for demonstration purposes so I could show you the whole file. Make it bigger than 1x1 when you test, or you'll never see it

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive answer, I can see what I was doing wrong with the PNG but it is still not working.  I edited my answer to show what I have now.  I get the results exactly as you say (in the prints and the saved file) but still do not get a rendered image in html.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Go in your web browser, and go to *"Developer Tools"* and open *"Page Source"* or however these are named in your browser and look at what your app sent as HTML, specifically the `<img src="...">` part.

Comment: Thank you, I was not decoding the base64 PNG.  Although the first code in the question I posted had it, I lost it in my revision.  To make it more clear, I posted an answer with the full functional code based on your answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I used Mark Setchell's answer and comments to come up with this full code.  I thought it useful to show what works:

```py
import base64
from PIL import Image

@api.get("/test_image", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def test_image(request: Request):
# Create image
    im = Image.new('RGB',(1000,1000),'red')

    # Create buffer
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Tell PIL to save as PNG into buffer
    im.save(buffer, 'PNG')

    # get the PNG-encoded image from buffer
    PNG = buffer.getvalue()

    # the only difference is the .decode("utf-8") added here:
    base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(PNG).decode("utf-8")

    return templates.TemplateResponse("display_image.html", {"request": request,  "myImage": base64_encoded_image})
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Display Uploaded Image</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>My Image 3<h1>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
   </body>
</html>
```

This included some troubleshooting from:
[How to display a bytes type image in HTML/Jinja2 template using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724304/how-to-display-a-bytes-type-image-in-html-jinja2-template-using-fastapi)

Comment: Please remember to properly `close` the `Image` and `BytesIO` objects, in order to release their memory (see related answers [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804), as well as [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804)).